# Opening a screen only works right the first time?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to show who a user is following / their followers. This works the for the first profile I click, but not for subsequent profiles.

1. Click on a user profile [**deven**]:

[image]

2. Click on **deven's** followers:

[image]

3. **Followers displayed correctly.** Click on a user from this screen:

[image]

4. Clicking on **elontuskstusk's** followers  brings me back to the followers page of **deven**, instead of showing me **elontuskstusk's** follower list.

How I open the follower/following page:

```
openFollowingList = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ClickedFollowPage', {
        clickedUID: this.state.userUID,
        followers_following: 'following',
        navigation: this.props.navigation
    })
}

openFollowerList = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ClickedFollowPage', {
        clickedUID: this.state.userUID,
        followers_following: 'followers',
        navigation: this.props.navigation
    })
}
```

Code for the follower/following page:

```
class ClickedFollowPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        
        clickedUID: this.props.route.params.clickedUID,
        followers_following: this.props.route.params.followers_following,

        //Other Stuff
        isLoading: true,
        navigation: this.props.navigation,
        userFollowerFollowingArray: [],
    }

    this.firestoreRef = 
    Firebase.firestore()
    .collection(this.state.followers_following)
    .doc(this.state.clickedUID)
    .collection(this.state.followers_following)
}

//Do this every time the component mounts
//----------------------------------------------------------
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection)

}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
}


_refresh = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection)
};


getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
    const userFollowerFollowingArray = [];


    querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
        userFollowerFollowingArray.push(res.id)
    })

    this.setState({userFollowerFollowingArray, isLoading: false})

    

}
```

I pass 1) which user was clicked, and 2) was the following or follower list clicked.

Based on this information, I query firestore for the correct list. This works, but only the first time.

Then, if I click on a user from this list and click on their follower list, I get returned to the previous user's follower list.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super simple solution. Change this.props.navigation.navigate to this.props.navigation.push

```
openFollowingList = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ClickedFollowPage', {
        clickedUID: this.state.userUID,
        followers_following: 'following',
        navigation: this.props.navigation
    })
}

openFollowerList = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ClickedFollowPage', {
        clickedUID: this.state.userUID,
        followers_following: 'followers',
        navigation: this.props.navigation
    })
}
```